# Difference between ngrep and tshark

Tags: networking

What are the main differences between tshark and ngrep?
Which tool gives the best results among these?

Comment: `man tshark;man ngrep`

Answer (score 1):

`wireshark` (`tshark` is the command line version) is a powerful sniffer which can decode lots of protocols, lots of filters, contrary to ngrep wich is similar to `tcpdump`, but has the ability to look for a regular expression in the payload of the packet, and show the matching packets on a screen or console.

It allows users to see all unencrypted traffic being passed over the network, by putting the network interface into promiscuous mode dixit wikipedia. Moreover ngrep also can be used to capture traffic on the wire and store pcap dump files, or to read files generated by other sniffer applications, like `tcpdump`, or `wireshark`.